# storing enum in signed char and comparing with enum fails in C

Tags: c, enums

I am trying to read an enum and store it in signed char. Later i am trying to compare the stored value with actual enum and it fails. Please let me know if anyone has leads.

```
typedef enum {
test1,
test2,
test3,
}Testenum;
```

in Main i have the below piece of code

```
signed char test;
int ret = sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &test);
printf("%c", test);
if ((ret ==1) && (test <= test3))
   printf("Success");
else
   printf("failure");
```

I entered "xxx xxx 1" and 1st print prints "1" and then "failure"  .I verified that ret is 1 so 2nd condition is failing.

Comment: The character `'1'` has a numeric value of 49 in ASCII. Try `printf("%d\n", test)`

Comment: The character `1` has numerical value 49 (in ASCII) which is not <= 2.  Perhaps you wanted to use `sscanf(..., "%hhd")`?

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the character value `'1'` to the number `3`, and it's greater than 3.  To compare the *number* `1` to the number `3`, you need to convert the character `'1'` to the number `1`.  You can do that by subtracting `'0'` from the character (assuming the character is a digit, since the characters `'0'` through `'9'` have consecutive numerical values in the character set).  For example:

```
if (test >= '0' && test <= '9') {
    int v = test - '0';
    if (v <= test3)
        printf("Success\n");
    else
        printf("Failure\n");
}
```